# Smarty - a set variable is not displayed when using if isset()

Tags: null, smarty, isset

I got the following code:

> {$productinfo.ProductPhone} 
>   {if isset($productinfo.Productphone)}
>   {$business_business_phone} {$productinfo.ProductPhone} 
>   {/if}

The first line is used as a witness and does return the phone number.
This value comes from database, so if there's no phone number, I don't want a random "phone:" hanging around (that's the {$business_business_phone} variable to handle multiple languages.

My problem is... {$business_business_phone} {$productinfo.ProductPhone} should be displayed since there's a value.

Comment: Are you sure the value isn't set? Perhaps you need to check if the `$productinfo.Productphone != ""` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked. It was indeed a problem in the database layer. It inserts an empty string. It's fixed :)

Thanks a lot